# UWP : How to Set Mindate and MaxDate for CalendarDatePicker Control in xaml

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am trying to use `CalendarDatePicker` control in uwp app .I tried to limit the date to `MinDate` & `maxDate` . I can able to set in c#  like below

```
Calendercontrol.MinDate=DateTime.Now();
Calendercontrol.MaxDate=DateTime.Now.AddYears(3);
```

Can you please let me know how to set `min` and `max` value in Xaml .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class inherited from CalendarDatePicker, add custom min/max dependency.

```
public class CustomCalendarDatePicker : CalendarDatePicker
{
    public DateTimeOffset Max
    {
        get { return (DateTimeOffset)GetValue(MaxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Max),                     // The name of the DependencyProperty
            typeof(DateTimeOffset),                   // The type of the DependencyProperty
            typeof(CustomCalendarDatePicker), // The type of the owner of the DependencyProperty
            new PropertyMetadata(           
                  null, onMaxChanged                    // The default value of the DependencyProperty
            ));

    private static void onMaxChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var calendar = d as CustomCalendarDatePicker;
        calendar.MaxDate = (DateTimeOffset)e.NewValue;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset Min
    {
        get { return (DateTimeOffset)GetValue(MinProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Min),                     // The name of the DependencyProperty
            typeof(DateTimeOffset),                   // The type of the DependencyProperty
            typeof(CustomCalendarDatePicker), // The type of the owner of the DependencyProperty
            new PropertyMetadata(           
                null, onMinChanged                      // The default value of the DependencyProperty
            ));

    private static void onMinChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var calendar = d as CustomCalendarDatePicker;
        calendar.MinDate = (DateTimeOffset)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<controls:CustomCalendarDatePicker Min="" Max=""/>
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks your reply . I have tried same but i am getting following error Cannot assign text value "10/2/2017" into property Min of type DateTimeOfffset. xaml -  <local:CustomCalendarDatePicker Min="10/2/2017"></local:CustomCalendarDatePicker>

Comment: I have changed Min and Max property type DateTimeOffset to string .now its working thanks

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please accept as answer pls :)